# Statistic - Population and Sample Mean Switching

Tags: statistics, means

I am figuring out a method to calculate the population mean via sample info. Is that possible?

For example, sample info sample size n=100, ̅x=53, σ=7.7.
The population size is 6700.
Can I calculate the population mean when P(x ̅≥53 hours)=0.5,

Can anyone give me hints and tell me is there any trading between population and sample mean? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a sample of size $n=100,$ the sample mean $\bar X$ will tend to be very close to the population mean $\mu.$

Furthermore, by the Central Limit Theorem,
$\bar X$ will have very nearly the distribution
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n} = 7.7/10 = 0.77).$

So you can say
$$P(\bar X \ge 53) \approx P\left(Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{10}} 
\ge 
\frac{53-\mu}{0.77} = 0\right) = 0.5,$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. Solve for $\mu.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for help

Comment: Sorry that I have one more question. For the case P(Z>=x)=0.5, wasn't the the x = 0? according to the z-score table. thanks

Comment: Question says $P(X > 53) = .5.$ My answer has that and also $P(Z > 0) = ,5,$ which is true of standard normal random variable, and shown in the printed table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!